# FullCalendar in Django

Tags: python, django, fullcalendar

So, I have an appointment models

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    doctorName = models.CharField(max_length=50)`
```

And I want to implement this in the `FullCalendar` tool. I'm not sure how to even begin. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is way too broad a question. What have you tried? What don't you understand? Have you created any views or templates? Can you load the javascript calendar in your templates?

Comment: I have views and template and everything, I don't really know how to implement js into my website

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since your question shows you haven't tried anything , guessing you know javascript and tried some hands on full calendar js.

Suppose you have model named Event for displaying different events in calendar.

```
class Events(models.Model):
    even_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name
```

In your views.py

```
def event(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    get_event_types = Events.objects.only('event_type')

    # if filters applied then get parameter and filter based on condition else return object
    if request.GET:  
        event_arr = []
        if request.GET.get('event_type') == "all":
            all_events = Events.objects.all()
        else:   
            all_events = Events.objects.filter(event_type__icontains=request.GET.get('event_type'))

        for i in all_events:
            event_sub_arr = {}
            event_sub_arr['title'] = i.event_name
            start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.start_date.date()), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.end_date.date()), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            event_sub_arr['start'] = start_date
            event_sub_arr['end'] = end_date
            event_arr.append(event_sub_arr)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_arr))

    context = {
        "events":all_events,
        "get_event_types":get_event_types,

    }
    return render(request,'admin/poll/event_management.html',context)
```

And finally in your template setup full calendar with including necessary CSS,JS Files and HTML code.And then ,

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2016-07-19',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                    start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',

                },
                {% endfor %}

            ]
        });

    });

</script>
```

Dynamically on some event you need to change events for example by changing dropdown you need to filter events ,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.event_types').on('change',function(){
            var event_type = $.trim($(this).val());
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'manage-event' %}",
                type: 'GET',
                data:{"event_type":event_type},
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    var event_arr = $.parseJSON(response);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', event_arr);         
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }


            })
            })

    })
```

Comment: Glad to see you have answered such a broad question with so much detail :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use following code to add, remove, update event in full calendar:

model:

```
class Events(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

view:

```
def calendar(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    context = {
        "events":all_events,
    }
    return render(request,'calendar.html',context)

def all_events(request):                                                                                                 
    all_events = Events.objects.all()                                                                                    
    out = []                                                                                                             
    for event in all_events:                                                                                             
        out.append({                                                                                                     
            'title': event.name,                                                                                         
            'id': event.id,                                                                                              
            'start': event.start.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),                                                         
            'end': event.end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),                                                             
        })                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                     
    return JsonResponse(out, safe=False)  

def add_event(request):
    start = request.GET.get("start", None)
    end = request.GET.get("end", None)
    title = request.GET.get("title", None)
    event = Events(name=str(title), start=start, end=end)
    event.save()
    data = {}
    return JsonResponse(data)


def update(request):
    start = request.GET.get("start", None)
    end = request.GET.get("end", None)
    title = request.GET.get("title", None)
    id = request.GET.get("id", None)
    event = Events.objects.get(id=id)
    event.start = start
    event.end = end
    event.name = title
    event.save()
    data = {}
    return JsonResponse(data)


def remove(request):
    id = request.GET.get("id", None)
    event = Events.objects.get(id=id)
    event.delete()
    data = {}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls:

```
from .views import calendar, add_event, update, remove, all_events 
url('^calendar', calendar, name='calendar'),
url('^add_event$', add_event, name='add_event'),
url('^update$', update, name='update'),
url('^remove', remove, name='remove'),
url('^all_events', all_events, name='all_events')
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events: '/all_events',
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true,
                select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                    var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
                    if (title) {
                        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: '/add_event',
                            data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end': end},
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                                alert("Added Successfully");
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                alert('There is a problem!!!');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                eventResize: function (event) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var title = event.title;
                    var id = event.id;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '/update',
                        data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end': end, 'id': id},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            alert('Event Update');
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert('There is a problem!!!');
                        }
                    });
                },

                eventDrop: function (event) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var title = event.title;
                    var id = event.id;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '/update',
                        data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end': end, 'id': id},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            alert('Event Update');
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert('There is a problem!!!');
                        }
                    });
                },

                eventClick: function (event) {
                    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?")) {
                        var id = event.id;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: '/remove',
                            data: {'id': id},
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                                alert('Event Removed');
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                alert('There is a problem!!!');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },

            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<h2 align="center"><a href="#">title</a></h2>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example**:To add event to fullcalendar you should add event to your model or if you don't want to save them you should create event and send to fullcalendar(in def calendar). For example to add event to all Sundays of 2020:

view:

```
def calendar(request):
        from datetime import date, timedelta
        d = date(2020, 1, 1)
        d += timedelta(days=6 - d.weekday()) # First Sunday
        all_sunday_in_2020 = []
        while d.year != 2021:
            all_sunday_in_2020.append({'name': 'my-title', 'start': d, 'end': d 
            + timedelta(days=1)})
            d += timedelta(days=7)
            return render(request,'calendar.html',{'events':all_sunday_in_2020})
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you add more code to add event like every sunday of the month.

Comment: but it is not working! I mean it shows only first sunday of the year not every sunday

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you did it right? copy all of this code and run it then see you get the output or not.

Comment: I got first Sunday of year at first in edited code(look at the fourth line of the Example code). You can get any time by using "date()" and "timedelta()" as I did.

Comment: calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); doesn't work because you hard coded the events in the html template, and are not getting them from a api

Comment: I updated the answer to include a working endpoint for refetchEvents