# Full Calendar in Django show events

Tags: django, fullcalendar

I am new to both Django & FullCalendar so any assistance that can be provided is greatly appreciated. My ultimate aim is to display events from an O365 calendar in Django using FullCalendar. Putting aside the O365 integration for now at this stage I am just trying to get FullCalendar to display the current events in my model. I have tried to emulate the solutions posted here [FullCalendar in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902405/fullcalendar-in-django/39904284) and here [Fullcalendar Does not display data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528561/fullcalendar-does-not-display-data?rq=1) but unfortunately the events are not displaying.

Here is my code:

models.py from my app called "bookings"

```
from django.db import models

class Events(models.Model):
    event_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    exchange_id = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    event_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    event_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    event_subject = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    event_location = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    event_category = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    event_attendees = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_subject
```

views.py. I've commented out the bits from the other solutions posted that relate to drop selection of category type. I have also tested using the below script in bookings.views.py, without success.

```
from bookings.models import Events

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CalendarPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'calendar.html'

def event(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
# get_event_types = Events.objects.only('event_category')

# if filters applied then get parameter and filter based on condition else return object
    if request.GET:
        event_arr = []
        # if request.GET.get('event_category') == "all":
        #     all_events = Events.objects.all()
        # else:
        #     all_events = Events.objects.filter(event_category__icontains=request.GET.get('event_category'))

        for i in all_events:
            event_sub_arr = {}
            event_sub_arr['title'] = i.event_subject
            start_date = date(i.event_start.date(), "%Y-%m-%d")
            end_date = date(i.event_end.date(), "%Y-%m-%d")
            event_sub_arr['start'] = start_date
            event_sub_arr['end'] = end_date
            event_arr.append(event_sub_arr)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_arr))

    context = {
        "events":all_events,
        # "get_event_types":get_event_types,

    }
    return render(request,'calendar',context)
```

and my template calendar.html:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          defaultView: 'month',
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true,
          events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                    start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                },
                {% endfor %}

            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am using mysql as the backend database. I have created one record for testing purposes. This is the record I expect to see in the calendar:

```
# event_id, exchange_id, event_start, event_end, event_subject, event_location, event_category
1, , 2017-09-13 08:00:00.000000, 2017-09-13 09:00:00.000000, test, , all
```

The calendar itself is displaying as expected, just without the event. If I hardcode test data into the template 'calendar.html' script the events display in the calendar.

Has anyone had any experience with FullCalendar and/or Django and can help me identify where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is rendered in your template, is `events` created correctly?

Comment: This included in views.py: from django.shortcuts import render. Is this what you mean? Sorry if I misunderstand your feedback

Comment: any JS errors in the console? Most likely there's something there, which might give us a clue. Either that or your code loop isn't actually looping over anything/

Comment: these are the only errors in the console: fullcalendar.js:3872 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event.  jquery.min.js:3 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 80ms.

Comment: hm. Can you verify that your `for i in events` loop actually executes and that the array being looped actually contains 1 or more items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this to get it working:

views.py:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CalendarPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'calendar.html'
    form_class = EventForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CalendarPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['eventlist'] = Event.objects.all()
        return context
```

and in the template:

```
events: [
    {% for i in eventlist %}
    {
        title: "{{ i.event_title }}",
        start: '{{ i.event_start }}',
        end: '{{ i.event_end }}',
        location: "{{ i.event_location }}",
    },
    {% endfor %}
],
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work for you.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          defaultView: 'month',
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true,
          events: events
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: _I think this will work for you_ Is not an explanation. Instead add an explanation to show how this will fix the problem.

Comment: your `events: events` results in error `(index):73 Uncaught ReferenceError: events is not defined`