# SwingTime in Djnago

Tags: python, django

I have a table in my ORM from which I want to calculate the total weight and display it on a calendar and for the same I want to use SwingTime but I was not able to use it.

**Models.py**

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    total_trucks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    offered_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now I can get the total weight like this:

```
total_weight = Quiz.objects.aggregate(Sum('weight'))
```

But how Do I use it with SwingTime?

I find another useful [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902405/fullcalendar-in-django) but was not able to understand it completely to use but it also solves the problem. Any help is appreciated.

[SwingTime](https://github.com/dakrauth/django-swingtime) : It is basically a Calendar on which we can show data from our ORM

What I did:

I installed and imported SwingTime onto my app, where I am getting stuck is that due to lack of my django knowledge I don't know how to pass it(total_weight) in the library.

**Output**

I got this from [this link](https://uggedal.com/journal/creating-a-flexible-monthly-calendar-in-django/)

It should look like this [image: Output]

Comment: What is SwingTime? What did you try to do with it? What problem did you experience?

Comment: Can you please clarify why do you want to use SwingTime, if you are getting result from aggregate?

Comment: @kamran I am getting the results from aggregate but to show it in the app as a calendar I am using SwingTime or any other third pasty Library such as FullCalendar But I am open to suggestions

Comment: So you would like to add total_weight at the occurrence of every event?

Comment: @kamran I don't want to create any event, plain text over the calendar will do just fine.. See I updated the question

Comment: @YantraLogistics SwingTime is event and occurrence scheduling application, please read documentation and try to apply as per requirements, and post in case of any error/issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195797/discussion-between-yantra-logistics-and-kamran).