# Fullcalendar in Django: TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-templates, fullcalendar

I have downloaded the FullCalendar library from [FullCalendar](https://github.com/rodrigoamaral/django-fullcalendar) and installed it.

**Views.py**

```
def event(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    get_event_types = Events.objects.only('event_type')

    # if filters applied then get parameter and filter based on condition else return object
    if request.GET:
        event_arr = []
        if request.GET.get('event_type') == "all":
            all_events = Events.objects.all()
        else:
            all_events = Events.objects.filter(event_type__icontains=request.GET.get('event_type'))

        for i in all_events:
            event_sub_arr = {}
            event_sub_arr['title'] = i.event_name
            start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.start_date.date()), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.end_date.date()), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            event_sub_arr['start'] = start_date
            event_sub_arr['end'] = end_date
            event_arr.append(event_sub_arr)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_arr))

    context = {
        "events":all_events,
        "get_event_types":get_event_types,

    }
    return render(request,'classroom/teachers/event.html',context)
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('calendar', teachers.event, name='calendar'),
```

**event.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load fullcalendar_tags %}

{% block content %}

    {% calendar %}

{% endblock %}

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2016-07-19',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                    start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',

                },
                {% endfor %}

            ]
        });

    });

</script>
</html>
```

**Settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
     'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
     'APP_DIRS': True,
     'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 'django.template.context_processors.request',
                               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', ], }, }, ]

INSTALLED_APPS = ['tempus_dominus', 'django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
                  'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
                  'django.contrib.humanize', 'crispy_forms', 'classroom', 'widget_tweaks', 'bootstrap_modal_forms',
                  'fullcalendar'

                  ]
```

When I try to run it, I get the error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /shipper/calendar
>
> fullcalendar/calendar.html

I am doing everything it says in the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902405/fullcalendar-in-django/39904284). But something is going wrong. Please Help

**UPDATE**
I have downloaded it from git and downgraded the Django to 1.8 and the demo works fine

Comment: Note that that project is tagged as "pre-alpha" and has not been updated in four years. But do you have `DIRS: True` in your TEMPLATES setting?

Comment: I have `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],` and `'APP_DIRS': True `in settings.py

Comment: Sorry, I meant APP_DIRS. Show the full templates setting.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Updated the question with Template settings

Comment: Hmm that should work. Is "fullcalendar" in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, I have fullcalendar in INSTALLED_APPS. I have updated the question again