# How do I use Django template tags inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

I am using a library called FullCalendar and I want my model data inside my template inside the javascript which I have seen many people do. But for some reason the template tags won't register as template tags and I get an error.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
var Draggable = FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable;

var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var checkbox = document.getElementById('drop-remove');



// initialize the calendar
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl,  {
  plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'bootstrap', 'interaction' ],
  themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
  selectable: true,
  select: function(info) {

    var titleStr = prompt('Enter Title');
        var date = new Date(info.startStr + 'T00:00:00'); // will be in local time

        if (!isNaN(date.valueOf())) { // valid?
          calendar.addEvent({
            title: titleStr,
            start: date,
            allDay: true,
          });
        } 
  },
  locale: "sv",
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
  },
  customButtons: {

  },
  eventClick: function(info) {
    alert('Event: ' + info.event.title);

  },
  editable: true,
  droppable: true, 
  events: [

  {% for event in events %}
                    {
                        title: "{{ event.name}}",
                        start: '{{ event.start|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                        end: '{{ event.end|date:"Y-m-d" }}',

                    },
                {% endfor %}

  ],

 });

  calendar.render();
  });

  </script>
```

the part that is not working is the {% for event in events %} loop, the view parses the model data into the template. I can for instance display the data in html tags but not inside the javascript for some reason? Someone to help?

These posts do the same thing and it seems to be working
[FullCalendar in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902405/fullcalendar-in-django)
http://qaru.site/questions/2365182/fullcalendar-in-django

Comment: When you do View Source on this code what do you see?

Comment: sorry, how do I view source?

Comment: @WilliamAbrahamsson In your browser, right-click, then "view page source"

Comment: Yea i get the HTML document

Comment: @WilliamAbrahamsson The code in {% for event in events %} loop.

Comment: the page source dosen't show the for loop tags at all

Answer (score 0):

Question is a little bit old, but i'll answer it anyways.

This worked for me.

```
events: [
          {% for event in events %}
             {
                  title: "{{ event.event_name}}",
                  start: '{{ event.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.start_date|time:"H:i"}}',
                  end: '{{ event.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ event.end_date|time:"H:i" }}',
              },
          {% endfor %}
        ]
```

Can we see your code in views.py? Thanks

Comment: Is it the corrct way I am using the external script file but without declaring the load static we cannot use the template tags right? Please anyone clarify the doubt?

Comment: Load static is not for template tags, load static means that you loaded static tag into your tamolate which can be used with static links.

Comment: // const Questions = [
//     {% for result in results %}
//     {
//         q : "{{result.questions}}",
//         options : ["{{result.option1}}","{{result.option2}}","{{result.option3}}","{{result.option4}}"],
//         answer :  "{{result.answer}}"
//     }

//     {% endfor %}   
// ]

Comment: I just added the comment for the separation of the lines in the code can u please help me with that. Actually I am making the quiz app using Django. So I am retrieving the data from the DB and I am validating and calucating the score but I did not added the code there. because there is a limit for the characters.