# Fullcalender display events in Django

Tags: python, django, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar in my in my Django project and I was wondering how I would get the model data to load as an event within the calendar. The issue is whenever I try to load the template into my code it loads up a white page with text in JSON format. 
I was wondering if it was possible to get by this.

This is how my model looks like:

```py
class CalenderEvent(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    event_description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name
```

This is how my view looks like:

```py
def calender(request):
    events = CalenderEvent.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactToAddEventForm()
        event_arr = []

        for i in events:
            event_sub_arr = {}
            event_sub_arr['title'] = i.event_name
            start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.start_date.date()), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.end_date.date()), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            event_sub_arr['start'] = start_date
            event_sub_arr['end'] = end_date
            event_arr.append(event_sub_arr)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_arr))

    context = {
        "events" : events
    }
    return render(request, 'calender.htm', {'form': form}, context)
```

This is how my template looks like:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "fullcalender/daygrid/main.css" %}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "fullcalender/timegrid/main.css" %}" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "fullcalender/core/main.css" %}" >
    <script rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "fullcalender/core/main.js" %}" ></script>
    <script src="{% static "fullcalender/core/main.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "fullcalender/daygrid/main.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "fullcalender/timegrid/main.js" %}"></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

          var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ 'timeGrid' ],
            defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
            events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                    start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',

                },
                {% endfor %}

            ]

          });

          calendar.render();
        });

    </script> 

<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div id = "calendar"></div>
       </div>        
</section>
```

I was looking at this stack overflow answer:
[FullCalendar in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902405/fullcalendar-in-django)

Comment: you've got two `return` statments in there - one which returns JSON, and one which returns a View. That doesn't make any sense. I don't know Django very well but I think `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_arr))` should be removed. There is a crucial difference between your version and the version in the answer you looked at - you haven't got the "event types" concept and you've remove an important `if` statement as a result. But you also forgot to remove other code which was related to that feature, most importantly the `return` statement

Comment: P.S. I actually think the design of that answer is not very good, a method like that should not really have two totally different purposes (i.e. returning JSON and returning a view), really that functionality should have been split into separate functions.