# Django - Unable to remove objects in the database through Full Calendar

Tags: python-3.x, django

I've been trying to implement Full Calendar in Django and I'am following this question [FullCalendar in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902405/fullcalendar-in-django). I have successfully rendered the data in my database in Full Calendar but failed to  implement a "remove/delete" function because of an error.

The error generated

```
    None
Internal Server Error: /scheduler/remove/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Emman\Anaconda3\envs\elxr\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Emman\Anaconda3\envs\elxr\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Emman\Anaconda3\envs\elxr\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Emman\Desktop\elxr\elxr\scheduler\views.py", line 42, in remove
    event = Appointment.objects.get(id=id)
  File "C:\Users\Emman\Anaconda3\envs\elxr\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Emman\Anaconda3\envs\elxr\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 417, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
scheduler.models.Appointment.DoesNotExist: Appointment matching query does not exist.
[02/Nov/2020 18:15:52] "GET /scheduler/remove/ HTTP/1.1" 500 80403
```

This is my models.py

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                           related_name='scheduler_appointments')
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
client_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
appointment_type = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
client_sessions = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

objects = models.Manager()

def __str__(self):
    return 'ID : {0} Client Name : {1}'.format(self.id, self.client_name)
```

my  views.py excluding the calendar function because I think the problem is in this function

```
def remove(request):
    id = request.GET.get("id", None)
    print(id) # prints None
    event = Appointment.objects.get(id=id)
    event.delete()
    data = {}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

my urls.py in my app

```
app_name = 'scheduler'


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.calendar, name='calendar'),
    path('remove/', views.remove, name='remove'),

]
```

and my calendar.html

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events: [
                {% for event in events %}
                    {
                        title: "{{ event.client_name}}",
                        start: '{{ event.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                        end: '{{ event.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    },
                {% endfor %}
            ],
            initialDate: '2020-10-1'
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,

            eventClick: function (event) {
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?")) {
                    var id = event.id;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "{% url 'scheduler:remove' %}",
                        data: {'id': id},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            alert('Event Removed');
                        },
                        failure: function (data) {
                            alert('There is a problem!!!');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },

        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in your template: `var id = event.id` should be `var id = {{ event.id }}`
Since the remove view prints none the id is not included in the request or is None. You can verify that if you inspect the request. Also you can inspect your javascript code (from your browser dev tools) and see if id has a value.

Comment: changing the code to var id = "{{ event.id }}" another error occurred ValueError at /scheduler/remove/ Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.

Comment: You are correct, event is the argument in the click function too. Make sure that the event object you are using has the right "id" attribute and that the request includes this id.

Comment: in the remove function in views.py print('Value sa id =', id) the output is blank or has no value

Comment: Yes, this is exactly why i claim that the javascript code has an issue. Check your javascript using your browsers developer tools, and take a look at the request you are submitting back to the server to see what you are sending - again through the browsers dev tools (network tab)

Comment: :8000/scheduler/remove/?id=:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) this was the issue. Im sorry I basically have no knowledge in Js and also a beginner in Django.

Comment: The error you sent suggests that  the item does not exist:
`scheduler.models.Appointment.DoesNotExist: Appointment matching query does not exist.`
you are either passing an id that does not exist, or you are not passing an id (which is what i assumed since you said that print does not show anything)

Comment: Upon checking the console GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/scheduler/remove/?id= 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: this means that the request you are doing from js does not include the id.
You can also try to skip javascript to make sure that the backend itself works by manually hitting http://127.0.0.1:8000/scheduler/remove/?id=<a valid id>
You can find a valid id by running `Appointment.objects.first()` from a django shell.
In fact if you run add ipdb in the view you will be able to debug it better: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html
For javascript you can type `debugger` on the line you want the execution to stop. Good luck :)

Comment: Really appreciate all your suggestions upon running http://127.0.0.1:8000/scheduler/remove/?id=2  or any ID's in my database the remove function does in fact delete the items in my database and maybe the JS is the problem . Thanks