# Use django filter in FullCalendar.io

Tags: json, django, fullcalendar

I am making a fullcalendar in my Django project, and I want to use django filters to filter the calendar. I have successfully created the calendar and the filters, but I can't get it to work together.

Does anyone have experience with including django filters (or another filtering approach) in a fullcalendar, or have a link to documentation that explains filtering in fullcalendar?

This is my view:

```
def kalender2(request):
    all_events = Timing.objects.all()    
    myFilter = CalenderFilter(request.GET, queryset=all_events)
    all_events = myFilter.qs

    if request.GET:  
        event_arr = []
        for i in all_events:
            event_sub_arr = {}
            event_sub_arr['title'] = i.event,i.name 
            start_date = datetime.strptime(str(i.start_time.date()), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            end_date = datetime.strptime(str(i.end_time.date()), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            event_sub_arr['start'] = start_date
            event_sub_arr['status'] = i.event.status
            event_sub_arr['end'] = end_date
            event_arr.append(event_sub_arr)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_arr))

    context = {
        "events":all_events,
        "myFilter":myFilter,
    }
    return render(request,'kalender/kalender.html', context)
```

This is the script and template of the calendar:

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      initialDate: '2020-10-07',
      locale: 'nl',
      slotMinTime: "08:00:00",
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      buttonText: {
        timeGridDay: 'Dag',
        today:'Vandaag',
        timeGridWeek: 'Week',
        listWeek: 'Lijst',
        dayGridMonth: 'Maand'
      },
      eventDisplay: 'block',
      events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    title: "{{ i.event}} {{i.name}}",
                    start: '{{ i.start_time|date:"Y-m-d H:i" }}',
                    end: '{{ i.end_time|date:"Y-m-d H:i" }}',
                    status:'{{i.event.status}}',
                    className: ["event","{{i.event.status}}"],
                    allDay: false,
                },
                {% endfor %}


            ],

    eventTimeFormat: { // like '14:30:00'
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        meridiem: false
    }
     
    });

    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class=flexbox-container-gantt>
  <div class = "flexbox-item-a-gantt">
    <form class ="filterform"method="GET">
      {{myFilter.form|crispy}}
    <button class="zoeken" type="submit"> Zoeken</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<div class=flexbox-container-gantt>
  <div class = "flexbox-item-a-gantt">
    <h1 class="title-box"> <i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i> Kalender </h1> 
    <hr class="box-line">
      <div class = "width_thing">
           <div id='calendar'></div>
      </div>
  </div>
      
</div>

</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

**UPDATE:** I changed the i.event to a string and now it filters the data. It shows the raw data on the page, and not on the calendar, presumably because of the url: http://localhost:8000/Kalender/?event=43&name=1&event_name=. But I am not sure whether this causes it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Nick, I assume that the error message refers to the line in your view, where you do `event_sub_arr['title'] = i.event`. Obviously, `i.event` is no string or primitive value what python can serialize easily. Please check this and write again, if this does not help! In general your code looks ok.

Comment: Hey Yves, thanks for your response. I have changed the i.event to a string and now the filter is working. However, when I use the filter I end up on a page which displays the raw data. I assume this is happening because the url is changing. I will edit my original post to show what I mean.

Comment: Hi Nick, I am not sure how well your solution in your `<script></script` works, when you insert the data from django with template tags. Fullcalendar allows you to retrieve the data via ajax from your view and takes responsibility of parsing on its own (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed). I could imagine that this works better.

Comment: Hey Yves, thanks again for taking the time to respond to my issue. I have now found the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902405/fullcalendar-in-django/39904284#39904284. The solution uses an Ajax call to update the calendar. I am still struggling to understand how to implement this inside my project, but the last part of the answer from the link should enable me to select a value and filter the calendar om that specific value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
# views.py

def get_events(request):
    all_events = Timing.objects.all()    
    myFilter = CalenderFilter(request.GET, queryset=all_events)
    all_events = myFilter.qs

    event_arr = []
    for i in all_events:
        event_sub_arr = {}
        event_sub_arr['title'] = i.event,i.name 
        start_date = datetime.strptime(str(i.start_time.date()), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        end_date = datetime.strptime(str(i.end_time.date()), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        event_sub_arr['start'] = start_date
        event_sub_arr['status'] = i.event.status
        event_sub_arr['end'] = end_date
        event_arr.append(event_sub_arr)
        
       return JsonResponse(event_arr, safe=False) # safe=False is important, because Json actually
      # does not know about 'arrays'
```

Your JavaScript can look like this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      initialDate: '2020-10-07',
      locale: 'nl',
      slotMinTime: "08:00:00",
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      buttonText: {
        timeGridDay: 'Dag',
        today:'Vandaag',
        timeGridWeek: 'Week',
        listWeek: 'Lijst',
        dayGridMonth: 'Maand'
      },
      eventDisplay: 'block',
      eventSources: [
         // your event source
         {
             url: {% url 'name_of_your_view' %} // here you specify the url of your view
             color: 'yellow',    // an option!
             textColor: 'black'  // an option!
         }
    ],

    eventTimeFormat: { // like '14:30:00'
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        meridiem: false
    }
     
    });

    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Hey Yves, thank you for the code you provided. It definately improves the data processing from view to template, and I think I will be able to use a select field to filter based on one dropdown. 

Unfortunately I don't think I will be able to use django filters in combination with fullcalendar. In your example the filtering should work, but I am unable to pass the myFilter from the get_events view into the kalender2 view (which has the template where the calendar is rendered).